# I want to save the recorded video and sound by recognizing the webcam in the web browser by streaming it to the server

Tags: javascript, webrtc, video-streaming, webcam, recordrtc

I want to save the recorded video and sound by recognizing the webcam in the web browser by streaming it to the server.

The duration of video recording is about 30 seconds to 2 minutes.

I checked the [PHP sample](https://muaz-khan.blogspot.com/2017/08/recordrtc-and-upload-to-php-server.html) that uses RecordRTC to send the entire video to the server. But I couldn't find a way to stream.

Please recommend a good way to stream webcam video to the server.

Please.